# Countdown to date function?

Tags: php, functions, user-meta

When a user signs up on my site they have to select a date as part of resignation.

On their profile page I need to show a countdown to that date. Something simple like attached. How can I create this function?

[image]

Comment: I would start by searching the web for `php subtracting dates`.

Comment: While you might be operating in a WP-environment, I fail to see what aspect of this is specific to that. Hence: How is this on-topic on this stack?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following function to display it

```
<?php
function days_to_go(){
    $datetime1 = new DateTime('2013-3-2');//Pass resignation date as a parameter.
    $datetime2 = new DateTime(now);
    $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
    echo $interval->format('%a days to go');
}
?>
```

For more information on date_diff function see [this page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php).

Answer (score 1):

I just found this question when looking for a function to create a dynamic countdown and I guess AJAX is the solution for me. I modified some code I found on a website (do not remember which one) and I'll post it here with the hope it will be useful to somebody. Here's the code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City'); //For some reason I needed this to get the number of hours right, it seems like strtotime and time() get different time zones if you don't specify a time zone
$nextThursday = strtotime("next Friday, 01:00 PM");
$remaining = $nextThursday - time(); //Calculating the number of seconds between no and the specified future date
$days_remaining = floor($remaining / 86400); //Dividing between the number of seconds in a day to get number of days
$hours_remaining = floor(($remaining % 86400) / 3600); //Getting the number of seconds that didn't complete a day and dividing them between the number of seconds in an hour to get the hours remaining
$minutes_remaining = floor((($remaining % 86400) % 3600) / 60);
$seconds_remaining = (($remaining % 86400) % 3600) % 60;
echo "There are $days_remaining days $hours_remaining hours $minutes_remaining minutes left and $seconds_remaining seconds left";
```